# Obtener datos JSON que devuelve una URL mediante Java

Tags: java, json

Estoy intentando obtener unos datos concretos de una petición http, esta petición me devuelve datos en json, aquí pongo un ejemplo:

```
{
    "Head" : {
        "RequestArguments" : {
            "DataCollection" : "",
            "Scope" : "System"
        },
        "Status" : {
            "Code" : 0,
            "Reason" : "",
            "UserMessage" : ""
        },
        "Timestamp" : "2016-06-20T08:15:41+02:00"
    },
    "Body" : {
        "Data" : {
            "PAC" : {
                "Unit" : "W",
                "Values" : {
                    "1" : 49
                }
            },
            "DAY_ENERGY" : {
                "Unit" : "Wh",
                "Values" : {
                    "1" : 56
                }
            },
            "YEAR_ENERGY" : {
                "Unit" : "Wh",
                "Values" : {
                    "1" : 771939
                }
            },
            "TOTAL_ENERGY" : {
                "Unit" : "Wh",
                "Values" : {
                    "1" : 3246052
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Estoy intentando sacar los valores numéricos de PAC, DAY_ENERGY, YEAR_ENERGY y TOTAL_ENERGY de la siguiente manera:

```
URL url3 = new URL("http://u020556.bi.ehu.es/solar_api/v1/GetInverterRealtimeData.cgi?Scope=System");

try (InputStream is = url3.openStream();
     JsonReader rdr = Json.createReader(is)) {

    JsonObject obj = rdr.readObject();

    JsonObject body = obj.getJsonObject("Body");
    JsonObject data = body.getJsonObject("TOTAL_ENERGY");
    JsonObject values = data.getJsonObject("1");
    System.out.print(values.getString("1"));   
}
```

Pero lo único que obtengo es `null`. ¿Alguien me podría echar una mano?

Comment: Pon bien el código, selecciona la parte y dale {} y agrega el log de error.

Comment: Intentas leer `TOTAL_ENERGY` sin entrar a la rama Data , por eso creo que te devuelve null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo he conseguido de la siguiente forma:

```
          try (InputStream is = url3.openStream();
               JsonReader rdr = Json.createReader(is)) {

              JsonObject obj = rdr.readObject();

              JsonObject body = obj.getJsonObject("Body");
              JsonObject data = body.getJsonObject("Data");
              JsonObject energy = data.getJsonObject("TOTAL_ENERGY");
              JsonObject values = energy.getJsonObject("Values");
              System.out.println(values.getInt("1"));
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Al tener un `JSON` multi nivel es necesario recorrer el objeto para leer los datos:

```
//Primero leemos el Body
JSONObject parent = (JSONObject) lev1.get("Body");

//A partir de aquí vamos bajando de nivel
JSONArray child1 = (JSONArray) parent.get("Data")

//Ya estamos en el nivel que necesitamos -- obtenemos TOTAL_ENERGY    
JsonObject data = child1.getJsonObject("TOTAL_ENERGY");
```

El resto de campos son triviales y ya accedes bien a sus valores.